# SQL: A query that return payment greater than the largest payment firms

Tags: sql

I'm trying to develop a query that list the VendorIDs of vendors who made payments greater than the largest payment of firms with VendorIDs of 34,35, and 83. Use a Sub Query. Show the VendorID and payments.
Below is my work. This only return result for VendorID 34.Is it possible to list the largest payment greater than the largest of firms with multiple vendorIDs (34, 35, and 83)?

```
SELECT VendorID, PaymentTotal
FROM Invoices
WHERE PaymentTotal > ALL

    (SELECT PaymentTotal
    FROM Invoices
    WHERE VendorID = 34)
```

Comment: Sample data and expected results would be helpful.  Maybe change your subquery to `select max(paymenttotal) from invoices where vendorid in (34,35,83)`...

Comment: I will try that. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

I know, this is an quite old question, but just to fill some holes:

Given your table was created with some sql like this:

```
create table if not exists Invoices (
  VendorID integer, PaymentTotal float
);
```

and there might be some data inside like this:

```
insert into Invoices values(1, 3500.5);
insert into Invoices values(2, 9500.5);
insert into Invoices values(34, 500.5);
insert into Invoices values(35, 700.5);
insert into Invoices values(83, 4000.5);
```

Then the VendorIds will be easily pulled out of your database like this:

```
SELECT VendorID
FROM Invoices
WHERE PaymentTotal > 
   (SELECT max(PaymentTotal)
    FROM Invoices
    WHERE VendorID in (34, 35, 83) );
```

Just tested with some recent PostgreSQL.